# "Loading" image doesn't show up

Tags: jquery, css, ajax

I have a div on my page with the following css:

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .35 ) 
                url('/NoAuth/cf/ajax-loader.gif')
                50% 50% 
                no-repeat;
}


/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

And I add or remove the "loading" class on the body when a .ajax call is made using:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('body').on({
      ajaxStart: function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('loading');
      },
      ajaxStop: function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('loading');
      }
    });
});
```

But much of the time, I find during the ajax call, the background changes color, but the gif doesn't show up.  If, however, I go to the Firebug console and type `jQuery('body').addClass('loading')`, the image *does* show up.  And when I look at the "Net" tab in Firebug, it shows that it didn't load the gif until I typed that .addClass command.

Is there something I need to do to pre-load that background so it shows up all the time, or what can I do to prevent this problem?

Comment: Stick the animated gif in the HTML instead of using it as a background and see if that works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it's because of the `display:none` CSS attribute.
Why don't you make it invisible when the document is ready ? The loading would appear during the loading of the document. Just remove the `display` attribute in `.modal`

And the javascript :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('body .modal').hide();
    jQuery('body').on({
      ajaxStart: function() {
        jQuery(this).addClass('loading');
      },
      ajaxStop: function() {
        jQuery(this).removeClass('loading');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: Of course, he could have a div that's meant to only appear when he's in the "loading" state.

Comment: I took most of this idea, but I changed it.  I put in some javascript to set the "loading" class on the body (the body comes from somebody else's framework, which is why I don't add it directly) and then in the document ready script, I remove the class before the .on call.  That seems to be, as @JayC said above, enough of a hint to the browser to load that image before I need it.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have any HTML elements matching a style rule in a referenced stylesheet, my experience is any resources related to the style rule won't be loaded.  One way to avoid that is to use [data URIs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/data_URIs) as that means the resource is already available *in the stylesheet*.  Of course, if you have to support certain older browsers (IE7) then this wouldn't work for you.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "don't have any items in the source with a particular class"?  Do you mean that I don't have anything with a "modal" class?  That wouldn't explain why it works when I manually set the "loading" class.

Comment: Sorry, that was really bad wording.  Edited.